# C# Socket remains connected when the other socket is no longer available

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

I've developed a client/server application in C# (WindowsForm) to connect two computers on the network.

Here's how it works:

-The client waits for the server to open up (yeah, i inverted the roles)

-When the server opens up, the client reaches the connection

Here's the problem: **if I close the server during the connection, the client remains connected**.

This is a problem because when I close the server (and the client remains connected), if I re-open the server the client doesn't connect anymore because *it's STILL CONNECTED* to the previous socket (the server that I closed)

I want the client (and the server too) to be able to **DETECT** when the other socket disconnects AND when this happens, I want the client to re-listen for incoming connection (as it was the first time).

Here's the source code of the client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace _Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            Thread connection = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
            connection.Start();
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            ListenForIncomingConnection();

            try
            {                         

                byte[] clientRequest = new byte[1024];

                while (true)
                {
                        int sizeOfRequest = client.Receive(clientRequest);
                        byte[] Request = new byte[sizeOfRequest];                            
                        Array.Copy(clientRequest, Request, sizeOfRequest);                           
                        string _stringRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Request);

                        // if the server sends a disconnecting message...
                        if(_stringRequest == "disconnecting")
                         {
                            client.Close();
                         }                     
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString());                
                DoWork();
            }
        }

    private void ListenForIncomingConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            client.Connect("x.xxx.xxx.xxx", 27018);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            ListenForIncomingConnection();
        }
    }


        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When the server disconnects, the client closes the connection with client.Close(). After, the client tries to reconnect to the server and I get this error: **Cannot access a disposed object**
This because, before the client tries to reconnect, I close the connection with client.Close().

How to resolve?

Comment: I don't use c#, but by the looks of it your "if(client.Available > 0)" is a pointless check. "client.Receive(clientRequest)" should be a blocking call. get rid of the if statement it looks like a tight loop.

Comment: @WalterM I updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "when I close the server"? If you close the server socket, the client should notice. If you end the server process without calling Close on the socket, the client cannot notice this as you are skipping the connection termination of TCP.

Comment: I close the server socket in the FormClosing event of the Server:

Comment: Are you calling `Shutdown()` on the server socket before close to make sure your "disconnecting" is sent to the client?

Comment: @Dunno can you post your solution please?